# How to not ignore in Laravel storage/app/mydir/myfile.json

Tags: laravel-5.3, gitignore

I am having a problem with gitignore in Laravel 5.3.

I have the following gitignore file. I used `!` to exclude myfile.json.

```
node_modules/
public/storage
storage/*.key
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
SQL/
*.sql
mynotes.md
!storage/app/mydir/myfile.json
```

When I run `git status --ignored` I get this outputs.

```
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../.env
    ../SQL/
    ../app/.DS_Store
    ../bootstrap/cache/config.php
    ../bootstrap/cache/services.php
    ../mynotes.md
    ../node_modules/
    uploads/.DS_Store
    ../storage/app/.DS_Store
    ../storage/app/mydir/
...
...
```

So myfile.json is ignored. How can I write a gitignore so that I can add/commit a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule to remember with gitignore:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**.

So check which `.gitignore` rule actually does ignore `../storage/app/mydir/`, because if it is a `.gitignore` located (for instance) directly in `/storage/app/`, it will have precedence.

```
git check-ignore -v -- ../storage/app/mydir/myfile.json
```

`../` means your current `.gitignore` is not in the right place: for a `!storage/app/mydir/xxx` rule to apply, it should be in a `.gitignore` file one folder up.

Comment: Actually it was one level down I found another gitignore by `git check-ignore -v -- storage/app/mydir/myfile.json
storage/app/.gitignore:1:* storage/app/mydir/myfile.json`. So I found another gitignore in storage/app/ dir. Can I add here !storage/app/mydir/myfile.json?

Comment: Yes, that would be the right place to add that rule.

Comment: Thanks. BTW when I modify the gitignore and `git status`, the myfile.json does not appear. Do I need to first add/commit this gitignore to take effect?

Comment: No, any modification to a gitignore is immediately taken into account by git status. Use check-ignore again.